# How to send data to specific xbee end device from a coordinator in AT mode?

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am working on a project where I have set up a small Xbee network (series 1) with Arduino. I am using AT-mode and my question is how to send specific data from a coordinator to a specific end-device? I've programmed the Xbee's in XCTU and I only use the serial in Arduino, that is I don't use Xbee library in Arduino to connect set up the Xbee's.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to go into command mode (don't send data for 1 second, send `"+++"`, wait 1 second) and set `ATDH` and `ATDL` to the MAC address of the target device.  Since all XBee modules have the same `ATDH` value, you'd only need to update the `ATDL` setting before you send data.

You would typically use API mode on your coordinator device so you can identify the source of serial data coming in, and easily address outbound messages to specific devices.  In standard AT mode, you just get a single stream of serial bytes from all AT Mode devices using 0 for `ATDH` and `ATDL`.